# Postgres: partition creation takes a lot of time

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which is partitioned based on `timestamp(daily)`. The table also has a default partition. We have a cron job which creates new empty partitions and drops older ones.
Because of some bug, this cron job didn't run and we ended up with a lot of data in the `default` partition. Now new partition creation is taking a lot of time. I found the following explanation for this

> Whenever you create a new partition, it has to scan the default partition to make sure that none of the rows in the default partition belongs to the partition which is newly created.

I understood this and thought creating an index on the partition key(timestamp) on the default partition would speed up the new partition addition. But this also didn't work, it still takes a lot of time to add a new partition.

Why is the index not helping? The following query is instantaneous

```
select count(*) from partitioned_table_default where timestamp > (now() + interval '1 days');
```

Edit:
I checked `pg_stat_activity` to see what this query is doing, it shows the wait event as `DataFileRead`. I also see a spike in the number of IO's from the DB. This indicates that it is still reading data from the default partition.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure why the check is so long, but maybe you can detach the default partition until all pending partitions are created, create a new default and then reattach the old default back again, but not as a default, but for a period between min(timestamp) and max(timestamp) from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the relevant code in `check_default_partition_contents()` in `src/backend/partitioning/partbounds.c`:

```c
/*
 * check_default_partition_contents
 *
 * This function checks if there exists a row in the default partition that
 * would properly belong to the new partition being added.  If it finds one,
 * it throws an error.
 */
void
check_default_partition_contents(Relation parent, Relation default_rel,
                                 PartitionBoundSpec *new_spec)
{
   [...]

    /*
     * If the existing constraints on the default partition imply that it will
     * not contain any row that would belong to the new partition, we can
     * avoid scanning the default partition.
     */
    if (PartConstraintImpliedByRelConstraint(default_rel, def_part_constraints))
    {
        ereport(DEBUG1,
                (errmsg_internal("updated partition constraint for default partition \"%s\" is implied by existing constraints",
                                 RelationGetRelationName(default_rel))));
        return;
    }
```

So if there is a constraint on the default partition that implies that no row in the default partition violates the new constraint, the partition doesn't need to be scanned.

```c
    /*
     * Scan the default partition and its subpartitions, and check for rows
     * that do not satisfy the revised partition constraints.
     */
    if (default_rel->rd_rel->relkind == RELKIND_PARTITIONED_TABLE)
        all_parts = find_all_inheritors(RelationGetRelid(default_rel),
                                        AccessExclusiveLock, NULL);
    else
        all_parts = list_make1_oid(RelationGetRelid(default_rel));

    foreach(lc, all_parts)
    {
        [...]

        estate = CreateExecutorState();

        /* Build expression execution states for partition check quals */
        partqualstate = ExecPrepareExpr(partition_constraint, estate);

        econtext = GetPerTupleExprContext(estate);
        snapshot = RegisterSnapshot(GetLatestSnapshot());
        tupslot = table_slot_create(part_rel, &estate->es_tupleTable);
        scan = table_beginscan(part_rel, snapshot, 0, NULL);

        /*
         * Switch to per-tuple memory context and reset it for each tuple
         * produced, so we don't leak memory.
         */
        oldCxt = MemoryContextSwitchTo(GetPerTupleMemoryContext(estate));

        while (table_scan_getnextslot(scan, ForwardScanDirection, tupslot))
        {
            econtext->ecxt_scantuple = tupslot;

            if (!ExecCheck(partqualstate, econtext))
                ereport(ERROR,
                        (errcode(ERRCODE_CHECK_VIOLATION),
                         errmsg("updated partition constraint for default partition \"%s\" would be violated by some row",
                                RelationGetRelationName(default_rel)),
                         errtable(default_rel)));

            ResetExprContext(econtext);
            CHECK_FOR_INTERRUPTS();
        }

        MemoryContextSwitchTo(oldCxt);
        table_endscan(scan);
        UnregisterSnapshot(snapshot);
        ExecDropSingleTupleTableSlot(tupslot);
        FreeExecutorState(estate);

        if (RelationGetRelid(default_rel) != RelationGetRelid(part_rel))
            table_close(part_rel, NoLock);  /* keep the lock until commit */
    }
}
```

Otherwise, PostgreSQL performs a sequential scan (`table_beginscan()` / `table_scan_getnextslot()` / `table_endscan()`) on the default partition.

PostgreSQL doesn't even try to use an index scan. I don't think there is a deep reason behind it, it just didn't get implemented.

Your way out is to create a check constraint on the default partition that is `NOT VALID` and just like the modified partition constraint. Then you can use `ALTER TABLE ... VALIDATE CONSTRAINT ...` to validate it without locking the table. After you have added the new partition, drop the constraint again.

My general advice is *not* to create a default partition if you plan to add more partitions later on.